# How to provide a variable in the for loop to loop through a range

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim FromRang As Range, ToRang As Range
Dim UserCell As Range
'Ask the user to input the cell Range in which to search for the sub strings
    Set FromRang = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Search Range From:", Type:=8)
    Set ToRang = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Search Range To:", Type:=8)

For each UserCell in ("FromRang:ToRang")
```

giving type mismatch error

Please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having looked at your previous question, you don't need two separate variables to capture the range.

`Set fullRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Search Range:", Type:=8)`
i.e. you can select the range while the input box is active. Also, you can type in `A1:A10`

And then, you could do

```
For each UserCell in fullRange
  ...
Next
```

Comment: @shahkalpesh Should the For statement not be "For each UserCell in fullRange.Cells"?